# If any spawned child processes fail, kill all and exit

Tags: bash, shell, python

In my script I split up a data set into input_aa, input_ab, etc. Then, I run each through the same Python script, as such:

```
# Execute program on each split file
for part in input_*; do
        python3 $part &
done
wait
```

My question is two-fold: how do I detect that a Python process has failed, and when detected, how do I kill all spawned children and exit the script with a fail?

Answer (score 11):

You could use a process group:

```
set -m
(
   for part in input_*; do
     (python3 "$part" || kill 0) &
   done
   wait
)
```

`set -m` (and optional POSIX shell feature, required Unix shell feature) runs jobs in their own process group. In `bash`, `yash`, `zsh`, `mksh`, that's jobs of the subshell where `set -m` is enabled so the outer `(...)` and all the processes created within that will be placed in that same process group.

For `dash` and other `ash` based shells, that only works at the top level shell process. So that code will work unless it's put in a subshell.

That won't work in AT&T `ksh` or the old SysV/Bourne shell at all.

`kill 0` sends a SIGTERM signal to to all the members of the current process group.

Comment: In bash.  Why I included a shebang - the required shell is not clear.  Good answer

Comment: @jimmcnamara, that works in `bash`, `dash`, `yash`, `mksh`, `zsh`. Basically any POSIX shell but AT&T ksh. `set -m` is (under-)specified in POSIX but as an optional feature.

Comment: I use Solaris. /bin/sh will not fly.

Comment: @jimmcnamara, no /bin/sh on Solaris 10 and before is the Bourne shell (not a POSIX shell), and on 11, AT&T ksh. As I said, it works in bash, dash, yash, mksh, zsh.

Comment: @mikeserv, what do you mean? A `setpgid()` or `setsid()` would get you out of that, not a double-fork.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - you can't break that like : `( ( some_process <>/dev/null >&0 2>&1 &)&)`? - i thought those kinds wound up in PID 1's lap.

Comment: @mikeserv, that would reparent the process to 1, but would not take it out of the process group. `kill 0` kills all the members of the process group whatever their parent is. See `ps -j` to see process group ids.

Comment: Great answer, tested and the killing works. Being a novice in Bash, how would I then have it called a Clean() function and return a failed exit? Currently it just kills and continues running through the rest of the program. Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: note that `set -m` is only necessary for non-interactive shells.

Comment: @Blauhirn, unless that code itself is in a subshell in a few shells as stated. Without it the `kill 0` would kill the outer-most subshell.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example.  PLAY with this first to get exactly what you need.  It cannot break much as is.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Example of killing off all children

> killfile
> outfile.err
kill_em()
{
   echo 'killing all children ' > 2
   while read pid
   do
      kill -0 $pid && kill -9 $pid  # if still running kill it
   done < killfile
   exit 1
}

export grandparentpid=$$
trap 'kill_em' 6
for i in 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
        ( sleep $i && ls oinkle  >> outfile 2>> outfile.err &
          pid=$!
          echo $pid >> killfile
          wait $!
          [ $? -ne 0 ] && kill -6 $grandparentpid
        ) &
done
wait
```

This is setup to fail deliberately because `ls oinkle` will fail (on my machine).

When you get what you need after tinkering with the starter script--- Change:

```
for i in 2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

to:

```
for part in input_*
```

change:

```
sleep $i && ls oinkle
```

to:

```
python3 $part
```

The redirections are there to save logs . You may not want them.

Comment: It's a bit racy. If one of the jobs fails before all the other ones have started, then your `killfile` may not contain all the pids of the jobs that have been started.

Comment: A few bad practices like: unquoted variables, use of signal numbers instead of names, use signal 6 (ABRT on Linux amd64 for instance) instead of USR1/USR2 as a user signal, `[ $? -ne 0 ]`...