# Kill job in subshell with set -m

Tags: bash, kill, job-control, subshell, process-groups

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
(
    (bin/pnvd &> /dev/null; kill 0) &
    sleep 2
    perl integration-test/fuzz-test.pl || kill 0
    kill %1
)
```

The first three commands in the subshell succeed and return exit status 0. `bin/pnvd` never exits until it is killed externally.

However after executing the forth command in the subshell, the script exits with this output:

```
tools/integration-test: line 8:  4712 Terminated              ( ( bin/pnvd &> /dev/null; kill 0 ) & sleep 2; perl integration-test/fuzz-test.pl || kill 0; kill %1 )
```

and status code 143.

It looks as if `kill %1` kills the whole process group, not just the first job, however if I remove `set -m` then it exits with status 0.

I am not so much interested in *how* to fix this but more in: *why* does the subshell exit with status 143 when it kills the first job?

Comment: That appears to be a feature not a bug. Stephane uses it in his solution here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179156/21233

Answer (score 2):

Quote from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7294947/402322

> Also, if the program dies because of a signal, bash lets you know by encoding the exit status as:
>
> ```
> 128 + signal-number
> ```
>
> Hence SIGHUP yields 129, SIGILL yields 132, SIGTERM yields 143, etc.

The above means, that your process has got SIGTERM.

You have three `kill`s in your code. If you can exclude `kill %1` one of the other two `kill 0` sends the TERM signal.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Please explain how this relates to the question.